# ActionScript3 - addChild() relative to another object

Tags: actionscript-3, addchild

I've seen code where an object can be added relative to another but I can't get it to work. I'm just trying to draw a rectangle and then add another smaller rectangle relative to the first

```
public var rectangle:Sprite = new Sprite();
public var other:Sprite = new Sprite();

rectangle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
rectangle.graphics.drawRect(250, 10, 100, 100);
rectangle.graphics.endFill();

other.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00);
other.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
other.graphics.endFill();
rectangle.addChild(other);
this.addChild(rectangle);
```

Both rectangles just end up rendered relative to the stage. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you do a diagram of what you're trying to achieve? I'm finding it hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: A smaller square inside of a large square. I could of course just use absolute coordinates, but local coordinates would make life much easier. I know it is possible but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Do you mean you just want to add a rectangle, say, 10 pixels to the left of another? In that case you just need to use: `rectangle.x = firstRectangle.x + 10;`

Comment: Ah, I suppose that works. I thought sprites are able to contain other display objects as children and that the children would be places relative to the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add sprites as children to a sprite. But your problem is that you never changed the coordinates of your two sprites. So there is no visual difference that you can see because the stage and the parent sprite have the same coordinate system.

Try modifying the coordinates of the parent sprite and you will see the the child sprite moves with it.

Now to get a small rectangle inside a big one you can do like this:

```
public var rectangle:Sprite = new Sprite();
public var other:Sprite = new Sprite();

rectangle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
rectangle.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
rectangle.graphics.endFill();

other.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00);
other.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
other.graphics.endFill();

rectangle.x = 250;
rectangle.y = 10;
other.x = 25;
other.y = 25;

rectangle.addChild(other);
this.addChild(rectangle);
```

Comment: AH! My mistake was thinking that drawRect(x, y) was the same thing as rectangle.x and rectangle.y of the sprite. Got it now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when specifying coordinates to drawRect (or any other shape), no matter where it appears on the screen, the shape is *always oriented at 0, 0*. It's confusing and I'm not sure why it's set up that way, but the solution is always to draw your shapes at 0, 0 and then move them by specifying the x and the y. Then your child's x and y will be relative to the parent's.